# Only run on scroll and not on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {

        var t, l = (new Date()).getTime(), scrolling = false;

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var now = (new Date()).getTime();

            if(now - l > 400 && !scrolling ){
                $(this).trigger('scrollStart');
                l = now;
                console.log("scrolling ");
            }

            clearTimeout(t);
            t = setTimeout(function(){
                if (scrolling){
                    console.log("scrolling stop ");
                    $(window).trigger('scrollEnd');
                }

            }, 300);
        });

        $(window).bind('scrollStart', function(){
            scrolling = true;
            console.log("scrolling 1");

        });

        $(window).bind('scrollEnd', function(){
            scrolling = false;
            console.log("scrolling 2");


        });


    });
</script>
```

The problem is that when the page first loads, it registers scrolling right away, even though I have not yet scrolled

> scrolling 1
> scrolling
> scrolling stop
> scrolling 2

I want it to register scrolling on actual scroll and not page/document load/ready.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452960/window-scroll-firing-on-page-load?rq=1