# On Scroll fires automatically on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im halfway down my page as I have an anchor. I also have a window scroll event:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
});
```

When I refresh the page, the scroll event fires. Is there a way to prevent this on the refresh but still listen for the scroll event when the user scrolls?

Comment: use the function as $(window).on('scroll',function(){});

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452960/window-scroll-firing-on-page-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag variable to detect whether the scroll event is the initial scroll event or not, effectively stopping the callback function's execution for the scroll event on page reload.

```
var initialScrollEvent = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (!initialScrollEvent) {
    // callback function body
  }
  initialScrollEvent = false;
});
```

Comment: This works around the problem, without really understanding it, and it's a really naive solution. Why does a scroll event fire when the page loads? What if it's something else and there's some code calling `$(window).trigger('scroll'). Patching a symptom should be avoided in favor of fixing the root cause

Comment: @JuanMendes that's really good advice, will think about that next time before posting naive answers, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe your scroll code only fires if you refresh the page and the page is scrolled. That's because the browser will reload the page, and then scroll to the original position.

The solution suggested by Arnelle does not work well, because the scroll event only fires initially if the page was scrolled when you refreshed it.

**Hack Alert**

What I found that does work is waiting to set the scroll handler. Be careful, I'm using magic numbers that may not work on all connections.

```js
//Scroll the page and then reload just the iframe (right click, reload frame)


//Timeout of 1 was not reliable, 10 seemed to be where I tested it, but again, this is not very elegant.
//This will not fire initially
setTimeout(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
     console.log('delayed scroll handler');
  }); 
}, 10); 

//This will fire initially when reloading the page and re-establishing the scroll position
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log('regular scroll handler');
});
```

```css
div {  
  height: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

And yes, I know I bashed Arnelle by saying they patched a problem without understanding, and here I am, suggesting a patch. The only difference is that I think I understand the problem.

My main question to the OP is. Most scroll handlers that I've written work fine if called multiple times, what is the problem with your handler being called an extra time?

Comment: The OP didn't answer your concluding question, Juan, so I will. I hide an advertisement when the user scrolls the page. If I get a scroll event when the window is refreshed, it'll hide my ad immediately (when the **user** hasn't scrolled the page). Your magic number works for me.