# Scroll event runs even though i have not scrolled

Tags: javascript

The console logs this sentence 'hello' immediately after i refresh the page even though i have not scrolled on my mouse.

```
const changeOpacity = () => {
window.onscroll = console.log('hello')}
changeOpacity();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(window).scroll() firing on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452960/window-scroll-firing-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

`window.onscroll = console.log('hello')` - will immediately invoke the call to `console.log`

You should wrap the assignment in a function declaration, like this:

`window.onscroll = () => { console.log('hello'); }`

This way your function will be called each time a `scroll` event is detected. Here's an example of how this would work:

```js
const changeOpacity = () => {
  window.onscroll = e => { console.log(`hello ${e.detail}`); };
}

//Init the event handler
changeOpacity();

//Fire some scroll events to test our handler
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll', { detail: `scroll event ${i}` }));
}
```