# element.style loading whenever the page is loaded but it is supposed to function on window.onscroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a web page in which the top nav bar hides on scrolling down and shows up on scrolling up. I am using the code given below to do so.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-custom fixed-top" id='navHeader'>
     
<!-- all the elements of navbar like logo and menu goes here-->

    </nav> <!-- end of navbar -->
    <!-- end of navigation -->
    <script>
    var header=document.getElementById("navHeader");
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    navHeader.style.top = "0";
    } else {
    navHeader.style.top = "-50px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
    </script>
```

But the problem is the element.style should load on scrolling the web page sown. But it is loading initially when the web page is opened and the nav bar is not visible initially. When the web page is scrolled down and then up again at that time the nav bar is visible.

The Images Given below may also help you

Initally and on scrolling down[image: Initially and on scrolling down]

On scrolling up  [image: On scrolling up]

But when the page loaded for first time and untill and unless it is scrolled there should not be any element.style I guess.

Then Why is this happening and how can is I solve it.

Thanks for any help in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$(window).scroll() firing on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452960/window-scroll-firing-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is quite simple: just add this code right before the scroll event

> navHeader.style.top = "0";

some thing like this:

```
<script>
    var header=document.getElementById("navHeader");
    navHeader.style.top = "0";//Please add this new line
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    navHeader.style.top = "0";
    } else {
    navHeader.style.top = "-50px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you're setting the variable `header` to the element with the id `navHeader`, but then you're trying to set the style on the `navHeader` variable, which you haven't defined. Does it work if you change those references to `header` instead?

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet of what you are suggesting?

Comment: Sure--I would think it should look like this:

`<script>var header=document.getElementById("navHeader"); ... if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) { header.style.top = "0"; } else { header.style.top = "-50px"; }`